# Updating VHD of Azure VM ScaleSet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, autoscaling

I have created a VMSS on Azure using the vhd of my Azure VM.

How can I change the source vhd of VMSS to a new vhd ?

Get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Update-AzureRmVmss` and `Update-AzureRmVmssInstance` to upgrade VMSS instance.

If we want to use custom image to upgrades Azure VMSS instances, we should make sure this VMSS create by custom image.

If we create VMSS from Azure marketplace, we can’t use custom image to upgrades Azure VMSS instances.

Here is my test:

1.I create VMSS by custom image, and use VMSS [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage) to create it(managed disk).

[image]

2, create another VM image, and use this script to get the $vmss, and use Powershell to upgrades VMSS instances:

```
$rgname = "vmsss"
$vmssname = "jasonvmss"
$instanceid = "1"
$newimagereference = "/subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29axxxx/resourceGroups/jasonwin/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myImage"
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname
$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id = $newImageReference
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmssname -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMScaleSetName $vmssname -InstanceId $instanceId
```

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Also we can find the status of VMSS instances:

[image]

So, as a workaround, we can use template or PowerShell to create Azure VMSS **with custom image**, then use this script to upgrades Azure VMSS instances.

**Note**: In my test, I am use template create VMSS was managed disk, so we should use `$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id`

If you create VMSS was un-managed disk, we should use this `$vmss.virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.osDisk.image.uri= $newURI`.

Here is the official article about upgrades VMSS instances, please refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set).

Comment: Worked perfectly,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AS per the [FAQ on VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq) and VM in general, the VMSS runs on top of VHD. So, if you have a new VHD, then you could simply delete the old VMSS, and create a new VMSS.

here is how I picture your situation to be.

1. VMSS running top of VHD1
2. Now, I have VHD2.
3. Create new VMSS using VHD2 as the base.
4. Delete VMSS running on top of VHD1
5. Delete VHD1 as well if that is no longer required, and or push it to some backup for later reuse.

the issue itself seems straightforward, unless you are asking for something else, and I am making a fool of myself :)

if the issue is something else, then the question needs to be explained a little more so other, more experience azure folks can help you.

Comment: creating a new VMSS with the new vhd is a good idea.
But is there a way like to update the existing VHD ?
Also the IP would also change if I delete the old and replace it with new and other setting like autoscaling rules ?

Comment: 1. updating existing VHD? thats like trying to replace a chair on which you are sitting on. Unless you get up and allow the chair to be replaced, it wont work. same with VHD.
2. the IP address would change, but you can get a domain name - xxx.azuresomething.net  which is available in the IP configuration or something. Try that.

Comment: it can be done using Update-AzureRmVmss command and then providing the URI of the VHD.
Problem is its not accepting that VHD its giving someVHD type error.
Hope anyone could help me

Comment: ah! Then, I do not know that technique. I am sure someone more experience than me would post a answer soon enough :)